# Is there any queue if several Spring prototype-beans ask for one singleton-bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have several prototype-beans in which I would like to use one singleton-bean as it doesn't hold any state and has only some methods.

The prototype-beans may ask for the singleton-bean all in one time.
So **is there any queue or order in executing methods of singleton-bean or all the processes will be going parallel?**

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. The code will execute in parallel if you have multiple **threads**. It won't if you only have one. Whether you're using prototype beans or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Execution of which methods and what processes are you asking about? It's probably better to post some code to clarify your question.

Comment: Agree with @JBNizet your prototype beans get reference to singleton bean in same order it asked for it multi-threading is implemented it will give reference parallel. BTW why does it bother you ?

Comment: Singleton does not means that access to singleton instance will be synchronized - and that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks to all. As the execution of singleton-beans depends on the threads - now the issue becomes clear for me.